# Android: Transparent gradient view

Tags: android, view, gradient

I have searched for this question and found a lot of answers that and people claim that those answers work, and I do not doubt that. However, in my case non of these answers help. I need transparent gradient view under toolbar, so that when `RecyclerView`is scrolled, it is visible under that gradient view. Is it even possible?
I tried doing this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#e9e8e9"
    android:endColor="#30ffffff"
    android:angle="270"
    >
</gradient>
```

This, however, does not make any transparency. I also tried `"@android:color/transparent"`, but still no luck.

This is how layouts are:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_button_category">
    ....
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_button_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:dither="true"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: did you set background to `Toolbar`

Comment: I did, but this drawable is applied to a View that is located below. This view always has white background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Recycle view. The sample code is given below

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
 android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/gradiant
/>
```

Step2. gradiant from xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient android:startColor="#000" android:endColor="#000"
    android:angle="45"/>
 <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

This will help out.